# How to get the top n category names from the first column based on the product id in the first row in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

So here I have the product Id in the first row and the category names in the first column.
And each column shows the sold percentage of these categories corresponding to the product id.
Now I want to see the top 3 category names based on the sold percentage with respect to product id.

Is there any way to do that? I have tried index match and filter functions and was not able to achieve the desired result and I am not that familiar with query function so did not venture in that direction.

Can anybody help me with this please?

I have attached a sample image here---> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO7XC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

You can use a segmented `QUERY` with `MATCH` to check which column to sort the values from.

```
=QUERY({A1:H},"SELECT Col1"&" ORDER BY Col" &MATCH(K2,A1:H1,0)&" DESC LIMIT 3",0)
```

**Sample:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[MATCH()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472)

[Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Language_Syntax)

Comment: Hi, I think the above formula is useful and it totally what I wanted and your formula makes perfect sense to me.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula

```
=SORTN(A3:A,2,1,B3:B,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by query as following with G2 contains the number of the column containing the parameter

```
=query({A1:D},"select Col1,Col" & G2 & " order by Col" & G2 & " desc limit 3")
```

[image]